# After Nvidia driver update the kernal starts in Busybox

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, busybox

I recently switched to Ubuntu 23.04 from 22.04.3LTS. It was working really fine so I upgrade the NVIDIA drivers from the additional driver tab to the latest one and during the installation my laptop shutdown and after I reboot it started in BusyBox. I found a solution and able to boot in the older kernel version 6.2.0-20generic and it is running completely fine but when I opened about section in settings my NVIDIA Graphic card is not showing there instead the internal intel graphic card is shoeing there. Before update both the graphic card was showing.

Please help me to regain the Ubuntu on my latest kernel 6.2.0-32generic which is only boot in BusyBox or help me to active the NVIDIA graphic card in 6.2.0-20generic.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you remember which Nvidia proprietary graphics driver version you were using before you updated it to the latest version?